# Adding a base year index to R dataframe with multiple groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a yearly time series dataframe with few grouping variables and I need to add an index column that is based on a particular year.

```
df <- data.frame(YEAR = c(2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002), 
                 GRP = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                 VAL = sample(6))
```

I want to make a simple index of variable VAL that is the value divided with the value of the base year, say 2000:

```
df$VAL.IND <- df$VAL/df$VAL[df$YEAR == 2000]
```

This is not right as it does not respect the grouping variable GRP. I tried with plyr but I could not make it work.

In my actual problem I have several grouping variables with varying time series and thus I'm looking for a quite general solution.

Comment: could you explain what the example data frame *should* look like before and after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create the 'VAL.IND' after doing the calculation within the grouping variable ('GRP').  This can be done in many ways.

One option is `data.table` where we create 'data.table' from 'data.frame' (`setDT(df)`), Grouped by 'GRP', we divide the 'VAL' by the 'VAL' that corresponds to 'YEAR' value of 2000.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, VAL.IND := VAL/VAL[YEAR==2000], by = GRP]
```

NOTE: The `base` YEAR is a bit confusing wrt to the result.  In the example, both the 'A' and 'B' GRP have 'YEAR' 2000.  Suppose, if the OP meant to use the minimum YEAR value (considering that it is numeric column), `VAL/VAL[YEAR==2000]` in the above code can be replaced with `VAL/VAL[which.min(YEAR)]`.

---

Or you can use a similar code with `dplyr`.  We group by 'GRP' and use `mutate` to create the 'VAL.IND'

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
    group_by(GRP) %>%
    mutate(VAL.IND = VAL/VAL[YEAR==2000])
```

Here also, if we needed replace `VAL/VAL[YEAR==2000]` with `VAL/VAL[which.min(YEAR)]`

---

A `base R` option with `split/unsplit`.  We `split` the dataset by the 'GRP' column to convert the `data.frame` to a `list` of dataframes, loop through the `list` output with `lapply`, create a new column using `transform` (or `within`) and convert the `list` with the added column back to a single `data.frame` by `unsplit`.

```
  unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$GRP), function(x) 
          transform(x, VAL.IND= VAL/VAL[YEAR==2000])), df$GRP)
```

Note that we can also use `do.call(rbind` instead of `unsplit`.  But, I prefer `unsplit` to get the same row order as the original dataset.

Comment: I actually got it working with plyr and that made the implementation with multiple grouping variables a bit more straightforward than with your options:                                                                                             ddply(df, (GRP1,GRP2), transform, VAL.IND = VAL/VAL[YEAR == 2000])      These more modern techniques could be faster though.

Comment: @Antti The `dplyr` would be more advanced and would be faster when compared to ddply

Comment: Confirmed! It is much faster. I just first got confused with those %>% operators.

Comment: @Antti Have you tested with `data.table`.  It should be faster if I am not wrong.

Comment: I tried data.table but ended up having an error. I have several new variables created with ":=" but in the fifth one process halts with an error. So it did not work. Luckily dplyr is fast enough for my purposes.

Comment: @Antti I don't know why it failed.  With multiple variables, I would do something like `setDT(df)[, c('VAL.IND', 'VAL.IND2') := ...., by = GRP]`  The `...` part depends on whether you are applying on different columns or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another base R approach built around [`by()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html):

```
df$VAL.IND <- do.call(c,by(df,df$GRP,function(g) g$VAL/g$VAL[which.min(g$YEAR)]));
df;
##   YEAR GRP VAL   VAL.IND
## 1 2000   A   3 1.0000000
## 2 2001   A   1 0.3333333
## 3 2002   A   2 0.6666667
## 4 2000   B   6 1.0000000
## 5 2001   B   5 0.8333333
## 6 2002   B   4 0.6666667
```